# What happened to my vs code UI, it zoomed so much

Tags: visual-studio-code

### How my VS Code UI is Zoomed Like This ?

I am using VS Code Since long time but never faced such issue, today I was writing some code and by mistake pressed some button and my vs code is UI is zoomed very much, can someone help, the UI screenshot is attached below

[image]

Comment: Put numlock on the press `Ctrl + 0` (the 0 on the keypad), or open View dropdown and click Appearance -> Reset Zoom

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ctrl and +;
you need to press ctrl and -;

Comment: Okay bro this problem is solved, one more problem, the UI has changed to some different one now, it's showing in the middle why?, here is the screenshot link :- https://ibb.co/vDmmpyN (hosted on imgbb.com),, if you help me once again, it would be great

Comment: @Ashutoshkumar - please don't ask questions in comments to answers. Also, note that these questions are off-topic, as they're unrelated to programming. You might want to consider a forum specific to VSCode if you have questions about general feature sets, updates, etc.

Comment: @Ashutoshkumar - also- for future reference: probably a good idea to not refer to someone as "bro" - this isn't a Boys' Club.